# Seconds to Minutes conversion in PHP

Tags: php, linux, date, datetime

I am using below code to convert seconds into `minutes:seconds`

```
$dtF = new DateTime("0");
$dtT = new DateTime("500");
$dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%i:%s');
```

It is working fine in Windows, but not in Linux. I dont know the reason. Experts please help me out of this.

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Answer (score 1):

`0` and `500` of what? PHP doesn't know. Specify your units of time:

```
$dtF = new DateTime("0 seconds"); // aka "now"
$dtT = new DateTime("500 seconds");
echo $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%i:%s');
// 8:20
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/198202)

Comment: *"`0` and `500` of what?"* - Apples and oranges, *of course* ;)

Comment: Note that a DateTime object represents an absolute point in time; '0 seconds' will be relative to 'now': `$dtF = new DateTime("0 seconds"); var_dump($dtF);` - in certain edge-cases, using this syntax may lead to unexpected results (e.g., leap seconds).

Comment: I wonder if the OP's going to bring us some "take-out". A doggie-bag at the very least.

Comment: Still I am facing same issue with Linux environment

Comment: @teshvenk: and what would that issue be? Or must we guess? Ok.. My first guess is: Do you have php version bellow <5.3.0 on linux?

Comment: In Linux 5.3.3 I have used. Now I have used gmdate() to convert. It is working fine.